# IndexError: no such group

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I'm trying to combine the if statement of two lines to one line:

```
matchesSense = [[m.start(), m.end(), m.start()*3+i, m.end()*3+i] for m in re.finditer(seq._data, protSense._data)]
matchesSense = [m for m in matchesSense if m[2] < len(record._seq._data)]
```

```
matchesSense = [[m.start(), m.end(), m.start()*3+i, m.end()*3+i] for m in re.finditer(seq._data, protSense._data) if m[2] < len(record._seq._data)]
```

The code is working properly when the two lines are used. But when I work with the combined lines I get following eror: "IndexError: no such group"
Any idea why that error occurs?

I've already done a similar combination of two line like that, where no error occured:

```
matchesSense = [[m.start(), m.end()] for m in re.finditer(seq_record._seq._data, 2*record._seq._data)]
matchesSense = [m for m in matchesSense if m[0] < len(record._seq._data)]
```

```
matchesSense = [[m.start(), m.end()] for m in re.finditer(seq_record._seq._data, 2*record._seq._data) if m[0] < len(record._seq._data)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In two statement version,`m[2]` of statement2 refers to element `m.end` in the resulted inner list element of statement1. when you combine both statement you, `m[2]` refer to the second element of `re.finditer` and not for `m.end` of that element.
So, both versions are not identical in results.